# Quando e por que devemos usar SVG?

Tags: android

Eu desenvolvo para Android já tem bastante tempo, programo nativamente, pra ser mais específico. Mas ultimamente eu tenho tido algumas dúvidas com o uso de imagens no aplicativo. Uma hora ou outra iremos fazer algum aplicativo que use uma vasta quantidade de imagens e então surge um problema: precisamos de várias imagens para que, em dispositivos diferentes, elas não fiquem borradas.
Então surge como alternativa o `Scalable Vector Graphics` ou apenas `SVG`.

No **Android Studio** você pode criar um `Vector Asset`, que vai gerar um arquivo em `XML` para que você use em sua aplicação, no lugar de imagens normais.

A diferença é que você cria uma, pra usar em vários, como por exemplo:

> Scalable Vector Graphics

```
    drawable/ic_vector_name.xml
```

> Imagens Comuns

```
    drawable-hdpi/ic_image.png
    drawable-xhdpi/ic_image.png
    drawable-xxhdpi/ic_image.png
```

Ou seja, enquanto que em `svg` eu crio uma imagem pra usar em diversos tamanhos, com `png` eu tenho que criar uma imagem para cada tipo de resolução.

Mas a minha dúvida é, quando eu devo usar SVG? É recomendável iniciar uma transição de `PNG` para `SVG` no aplicativo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aprendi a vetorizar “coisas” no Corel Draw, e esse negócio das imagens não perderem qualidade é o máximo.(blablabla)

A  partir do Lollipop (API 21), o Android incluiu a classe [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html), para definir *drawables* com base em gráficos vetoriais. O **Android Studio 1.4** acrescenta o **Vector Asset Studio** para torná-los mais fáceis de trabalhar, incluindo um recurso de importação SVG e um novo plugin Gradle que gera versões PNG de ícones `VectorDrawable` em tempo de compilação para a API 20 e versões anteriores. Há também ferramentas de terceiros para converter SVGs para `VectorDrawables`. Tenha em mente que, embora o vetor *drawables* pode ser definido em XML, o formato de arquivo não é SVG e nem todos os arquivos SVG podem ser convertidos com êxito.

> É recomendável iniciar uma transição de PNG para SVG no aplicativo?

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html), o uso de caracteres vetoriais em vez de *bitmaps* reduz o tamanho do APK porque o mesmo arquivo pode ser redimensionado para diferentes densidades de tela sem perda de qualidade de imagem.

Temos que cada biblioteca adicionada a um projeto traz muitas possibilidades e características, porém as bibliotecas normalmente contêm uma grande quantidade de arquivos de código e recursos, dentre elas, recursos desnecessários dependendo de cada tipo de situação. Isso cria uma espécie de resíduo: os aplicativos têm um monte de coisas que nunca são realmente utilizadas. Mais do que isso, o tamanho dos pacotes estão crescendo em um ritmo rápido. A questão é que, devemos tentar diminuir o máximo possível

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta imagem encontrada [no Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) que define melhor sobre o [**Scalable Vector Graphics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), ilustra a diferença entre bitmap e imagens vetoriais. A imagem `bitmap` é composta de um conjunto fixo de *pixels*, enquanto a imagem vetorial é composta de um conjunto fixo de formas. Na imagem, a escala do `bitmap` revela os *pixels* ao dimensionar a imagem vetorial preserva as formas.

Leia [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Consegui esclarecer algumas das dúvidas que eu tinha, eu aprendi a Vetorizar com o Illustrator, mas enfim, obrigado. Éh nóis

Answer (score 4):

SVG pode ser usado para substituir imagens, normalmente ícones.
O uso de SVG é sempre indicado por ser muito mais leve que um PNG, JPG, por exemplo.

A grande vantagem é que, por se tratar de um vetor, ele nunca irá perder qualidade, como aconteceria com uma imagem.

Recomendo a leitura:
[Imagens em SVG](https://tableless.com.br/imagens-em-alta-resolucao-utilizando-svg/)