# Como resolver a distorção que ocorre quando mudo o app de portrait para landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout

Visualização normal (portrait)

[image]

Para o modo de exibição ela fica normal, como podem ver, agora quando coloco no modo landscape...

[image]

Gostaria que o background não ficasse distorcido, como na imagem acima. Para isso gostaria que listassem uma forma de exibir uma outra imagem como fundo quando o app fosse colocado na horizontal (landscape) ou para que a imagem que coloquei não distorcesse, se existe algum tamanho que o android detecte, enfim...

OBS - JÁ CRIEI UMA IMAGEM PARA O MODO HORIZONTAL, SÓ NÃO SEI HÁ A POSSIBILIDADE DE COLOCÁ-LA PARA SER EXIBIDA SOMENTE QUANDO O APP TIVER EM MODO LANDSCAPE.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Veja na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem duas possíveis respostas para a sua pergunta. A primeira, e a que qualquer um iria responder, é a que o [@Ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral) citou.

Em citação ao comentário dele, irei resumir como resposta. Você vai ter que criar duas imagens, com o mesmo nome, mas com resoluções adequadas para `lang` e `port`. Para fazer isso, sua configuração em `/res` deveria ficar assim:

```
Drawable-land  
      imagem.png   

Drawable-port
      imagem.png
```

Existe um porém ao realizar tal configuração: você precisaria ficar criando duas imagens para cada tipo de resolução, o que é um tanto prejudicial.

A segunda resposta é a mais simples e mais compacta. Você cria apenas uma imagem e usa ela em qualquer resolução, porque a imagem é auto redimensionável.

A resposta vem de uma pergunta que eu mesmo fiz: [Quando e por que devemos usar SVG?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171678/quando-e-por-que-devemos-usar-svg)

Se utilizarmos `SVG`, criamos apenas um arquivo e utilizamos ele em diferentes resoluções, sem que ele perca a qualidade. Segue a resposta:

> Aprendi a vetorizar “coisas” no Corel Draw, e esse negócio das imagens não perderem qualidade é o máximo.(blablabla)
>
> A  partir do Lollipop (API 21), o Android incluiu a classe [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html), para definir *drawables* com base em gráficos vetoriais. O **Android Studio 1.4** acrescenta o **Vector Asset Studio** para torná-los mais fáceis de trabalhar, incluindo um recurso de importação SVG e um novo plugin Gradle que gera versões PNG de ícones `VectorDrawable` em tempo de compilação para a API 20 e versões anteriores. Há também ferramentas de terceiros para converter SVGs para `VectorDrawables`. Tenha em mente que, embora o vetor *drawables* pode ser definido em XML, o formato de arquivo não é SVG e nem todos os arquivos SVG podem ser convertidos com êxito.
>
> É recomendável iniciar uma transição de PNG para SVG no aplicativo?
>
> De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html), o uso de caracteres vetoriais em vez de *bitmaps* reduz o tamanho do APK porque o mesmo arquivo pode ser redimensionado para diferentes densidades de tela sem perda de qualidade de imagem.
>
> Temos que cada biblioteca adicionada a um projeto traz muitas possibilidades e características, porém as bibliotecas normalmente contêm uma grande quantidade de arquivos de código e recursos, dentre elas, recursos desnecessários dependendo de cada tipo de situação. Isso cria uma espécie de resíduo: os aplicativos têm um monte de coisas que nunca são realmente utilizadas. Mais do que isso, o tamanho dos pacotes estão crescendo em um ritmo rápido. A questão é que, devemos tentar diminuir o máximo possível

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Esta imagem encontrada no Wikipedia que define melhor sobre o [**Scalable Vector Graphics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), ilustra a diferença entre bitmap e imagens vetoriais. A imagem bitmap é composta de um conjunto fixo de pixels, enquanto a imagem vetorial é composta de um conjunto fixo de formas. Na imagem, a escala do bitmap revela os pixels ao dimensionar a imagem vetorial preserva as formas.
>
> Leia [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Desde já agradecido pela resposta. Verei o que farei baseado no que me respondeu...

[...] A partir do Lollipop (API 21), o Android incluiu a classe VectorDrawable, para definir drawables com base em gráficos [...]"

Estou fazendo um app para Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.3 API 15), creio que não poderei utilizar isso em específico.

Comment: Isso não é necessário. Tu pode usar o [VectorAsset](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) normalmente. Tu vai criar um Vector  a partir de um .svg e vai transformar ele em um arquivo `xml` e usar como imagem. É bem simples.

Comment: Não esquecer que o suporte a SVG é limitado, além que o seu uso é apenas apropriado para *icons*.

Comment: Já baixei o inkscape aqui. Começarei os testes.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível, recorrendo a [qualificadores de configuração](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), que permitem você controlar como o sistema selecciona recursos alternativos com base nas características da tela do dispositivo actual.

Os qualificadores de configuração são strings que são adicionados aos nomes dos directórios de recursos do projecto Android.

No seu caso deve criar uma pasta com o nome ***res/drawable-land*** e colocar lá a imagem que quer que seja usada quando o dispositivo estiver na posição *landscape*. Ela deve ter o mesmo nome da usada em modo *portrait*.

Comment: Desde já agradecido!!!

Acessei o link que você colocou, tentei criar essa pasta, mas nada apareceu.

Comment: Foi porque você fez algo de errado. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150452/2541) como deve criar a pasta.

Comment: A pasta não apareceu no Android Studio, mas apareceu quando fui vê-la no explorer. Criada ela foi de fato e adicionei a segunda imagem.

Porém ela apareceu no diretório drawable com "(land)" ao lado.

Comment: Veja a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150452/2541) que indiquei, lá é explicado porque não vê  a pasta.

Comment: Muito útil!!! Vi que é sempre bom ficar alternando, dependendo da necessidade do momento. VLW ^-^